# block ip by hwid from a text file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working o a project that monitors the IP and HWID on a specific port by TCPListen sent from a client that kills a specific process.

Monitor works perfect, I receive ip and hwid and manage to save to .txt files but what I want to do is to implement  a method in server how to block the ip by reading the hwid from a text file.
If some one can help me please I will appreciate it really.

Here is a part from code of client(send)  , server (receive):

Server:

```
textFromClient = ("From:  " + tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint + " HWID:" + encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```

Client:

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(getUniqueID("C"));
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

---

I think I understand but maybe that I didn't explain right. Well, my server listen on any ip on port 8000 . Clients connects automaticly to server ip and port: exemple : 127.0.0.1:8000. Well clients works like this: When client is connected to server it runs a application".exe". Client is made to kill the process of some application by name. I made a timer for kill the process  all the time client is running. When a process is killed client sends to server the IP from pc where process was killed and HWID code: `byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(getUniqueID("C"));
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();` and server recive on a listbox the ip and hwid. Well i'm thinking to do so . Example: On this recive message code where i get the HWID from client `encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead)` to do something like:

```
if (encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead) = LoadBlockHWID(new FileInfo(@"c:\testfileHWID.txt")));
```

{

//Code to block connection from specified IP on hwid.

}

I whant that server  should not let the client connect to server by HWID. I think I must edit server to see ip and hwid connected and client to send hwid when connected.

Comment: I think you need to show a little more of what you are trying to do with regard to this "block". Do you want to protect certain HWID from being passed in or block certain IP's from doing it?

Comment: No , I want to block certain IP that I recived from client by hwid recived from client with ip in same time. Exemple : I get mesege on server from client:"From IP: 127.0.0.1:54137 , HWID: 3928824234AD". Now I want to block ip: 127.0.0.1 by HWID that can be found in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your HWID into a List/Dictionary by reading your file before you start accepting connections.

in your code where you get tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint, extract just the IPAddress out of that.

Then compare the IPAddress to the block list and if it matches, then see if the HWID matches if that matches then don't perform the task otherwise just do it.

```
mBlockCheck = new SO15147104();
```

Here is an example for you. Just instantiate the class and in your line where you Might want to block a request, just

```
if (!mBlockCheck.BlockRequest(ip, hwid))
{
    //Do the operation
}
```

This is the class code you should be able to figure out from this.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

public class SO15147104
{
    private List<string> HWIDLookup;
    private List<IPAddress> IPAddressLookup;

    public SO15147104()
    {
        HWIDLookup = LoadBlockHWID(new FileInfo(@"c:\testfileHWID.txt"));
        IPAddressLookup = LoadBlockIPAddresses(new FileInfo(
                                               @"c:\testfileIPAddresses.txt"));
    }


    public bool BlockRequest(IPAddress ip, string HWIDtoCheck)
    {
        if (IPAddressLookup.Contains(ip) &&
            HWIDLookup.Contains(HWIDtoCheck.ToUpperInvariant().Trim()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private List<IPAddress> LoadBlockIPAddresses(FileInfo fi)
    {
        List<IPAddress> result = new List<IPAddress>();

        using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                IPAddress theIP = IPAddress.Any;
                string thisLine = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
                //This should allow IPv6 and IPv4 to be listed 1IP per Line
                if (IPAddress.TryParse(thisLine, out theIP))
                {
                    result.Add(theIP);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }



    private List<string> LoadBlockHWID(FileInfo fi)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                result.Add(sr.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpperInvariant());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide me some code exemple if posible? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I try do my best.

Comment: Can you provide me a email where can I send u the code if posibble? I got some issue. Thank you!